# iOS: Copy files from Office app to my app's documents

Tags: ios, onedrive

I'm not sure if this is a programming issue, but hopefully somebody can help me out anyway. On my iPhone (iOS 13.3) I'm trying to copy a file from OneDrive into my app's document folder using the Files app. I already set the keys `UIFileSharingEnabled` and `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` in the info.plist file so my app appears e.g. in the iTunes FileSharing section. It also appears as a possible target when I share a picture from the "Photos" app or if the source in "Files" is a standard app. But whenever the source is an MS Office app (OneDrive / Excel / Word / ...), the target app list is reduced to Office apps. No other app - neither mine nor standard apps like "Pages" or "Numbers" - appears in the list.

Does my app need a special setting to retrieve OneDrive files, or is this a more general Office issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously this is caused by a restriction defined by my company's IT department. Sorry to bother you.